# Uniform convergence and Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{1+nx^2}$ and $f(x)=0$.

(i) Prove $f_n \to f$ uniformly.

(ii) Calculate $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1} f_n(x)dx$  in $2$ ways.

(iii) For what values of $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is it true that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}} f'_n(x) = f'(x)?$

For (i) I set $M_n = sup|f_n(x)-0| < \frac{1}{x}$. Since $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}} \frac{1}{x} \to 0$ the convergence is uniform. (I am not positive this is correct)

For (ii) we proved we can take the limit inside the integral, so we get $\displaystyle{\int_0^1} f(x) dx= 0$. I directly did the integral then took the limit and once again got $0$. Is this legal to do? I cannot think of any other way to do this.

For (iii) The left hand side is $0$ so then when is $\frac{1-x^2}{x^4+2x^2+1} = 0$. This is only true at $x=1,-1$.

Comment: In (i) the limit should be as $x\rightarrow\infty$ right?

Comment: Yep! Ill fix it.

Comment: For (ii), taking the limit inside the integral is correct to do because you have already proved (i) that is, that uniform convergence holds.

Comment: If you want to apply the M-test in (i) you need a bound involving $n$ somehow, so that $lim_{n\to\infty}M_n=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In (i) It would be $lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ I think.

Answer (score 1):

(i) is incorrect: you did not understand how to prove uniform convergence.

$$
M_n = \sup_x \frac{|x|}{1 + nx^2}
$$
You want to prove that this goes to 0 when $n\to\infty$.

We have : 
$$
\frac{|x|}{1 + nx^2} \le \frac{|x|}{ nx^2} = \frac 1 {n|x|}
$$but it is not small when $x$ is close to 0.

Let $r>0$.

- For $x$ small, the numerator is small:
  $$
  \frac{|x|}{1 + nx^2} \le |x| \le r
  $$
  when $|x| \le r$.
- Otherwise, 
  $$
  \frac{|x|}{1 + nx^2} \le \frac 1 {n|x|} \le \frac 1 {nr} \le \frac 1 r
  $$
  as soon as $n> \frac 1 {r^2}$.

$$
n> \frac 1 {r^2} \Rightarrow M_n \le r
$$
that is $$M_n\to_{n\to\infty} 0 $$

(ii) is correct.

(iii) is not, there is a mistake in your computation (where is $n$?).
See the edit by OP in the comments for the solution.

Comment: I took the limit as $n\to\infty$. So there wouldn't be one.

Comment: @Skuttle_Butt you have to take the limit *after* you differentiate, not before.

Comment: $f'_n(x) = \frac{1-nx^2}{(nx^2+1)^2}$. As $n\to\infty$ this goes to $0$.

Comment: This is better!

Comment: Is there anyway to do (i) for any $x$ and not split it into cases?